# Reversing the order of a string value

Tags: swift, function, character

I have the following function which reverses a string value's display order. 
I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to understand it's logic. What is going on with the '!pleh' value that it turns into 'Help!' ? 
Thanks

```
func reverse(_ s: String) -> String {
 var str = ""
 for character in s.characters {
    str = "\(character)" + str
 }
 return str
}
print (reverse("!pleH"))
```

Comment: The `print (reverse("!pleH"))` statement is not part of the `reverse` function. Pretty sure it's just to demonstrate the function and is not consequential to actually reversing a string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Commented inline,

```
func reverse(_ s: String) -> String {
 var str = ""
 //.characters gives the character view of the string passed. You can think of it as array of characters.
 for character in s.characters {
    str = "\(character)" + str
    //This will help you understand the logic. 
    //!+""
    //p+!
    //l+p! ... goes this way
    print ( str)
 }
 return str
}
print (reverse("!pleH"))
```

Comment: most of the time, in those simple questions, we need to know how to do it without a function for it. and you made it simply.
congrats

Answer (score 18):

In swift 4.0, directly call `reversed` on a string will get the job done

```
let str = "abc"
String(str.reversed()) // This will give you cba
```

Comment: are you sure..?

Comment: I need to know the implementation or Definition of this `reversed()` function in Xcode. How do i do that ? I already tried Jump To Definition but I can't find the function's body.

Answer (score 15):

Note: If you don't want to use the `reversed()` in-built function, then you can use the following code.

**One-liner using Higher-order function "*Reduce*" on the string.**

```
extension String {
func reverse() -> String  { return self.reduce("") { "\($1)" + $0 } }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The function `reversed(_:)` iterates over each `Character` in the supplied string `s`, and simply concenates them in the reverse order.

```
// 1st pass in the 'for' loop:
//    @ start of iteration: 'str' equals ""
//    update value of 'str' according to
//    str = aCharacterAsString + str = "!" + ""

// 2nd pass in the 'for' loop:
//    @ start of iteration: str equals "!"
//    update value of 'str' according to
//    str = anotherCharacterAsString + str = "p" + "!"

// 3rd pass in the 'for' loop:
//    @ start of iteration: str equals "p!"
//    update value of 'str' according to
//    str = yetAnotherCharacterAsString + str = "l" + "p!"

// and so on ...

// after end of 'for' loop: str == "help!"

// this value of 'str' is then return to callee (which prints it)
```

A much simpler approach would be using `reversed()` on the `CharacterView` of the `String` instance:

```
let str = "!pleH"
print(String(str.characters.reversed())) // Help!
```

**Swift 4** You can use it directly in your string

```
let str = "!pleH"
print(String(str.reversed())) // Help!
```

Comment: wow I never looked at it that way... Thanks for the quick reply this is my first week learning how to code!

Comment: @Leo, you made Fangming's answer redundant by adding that solution to this answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew his answer could also be just a comment in this answer

Comment: Note: as the *reversed* function returns a collection of characters, not a String that's why we convert that collection back into a String using the String initializer.

Comment: How is the performance of `String(str.reversed())`? Especially when dealing with super long `String` in Swift?

Answer (score 7):

```
var string = "My,playground and my Swift" 
var reverseString = ""  
for str in string { 
    reverseString.insert(str, at: reverseString.startIndex) 
}  
print(reverseString)
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 4 - To reverse string  ::**

```
func reverse(string:String) -> String {

    var reverse = ""

    for char  in string {

        reverse = char.description + reverse
    }
    return reverse
}
```

> **Input** :: reverse(string: "Ashish Chhabra")
>
> **Output** :: arbahhC hsihsA

Answer (score 2):

```
var strnew = "hello world new" 

var reverseStr = ""

for each in strnew
{
    reverseStr = String(each) + reverseStr
}

print(reverseStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = readLine()!
var resultString = ""
for i in 1...string.count {
    let index = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -i)
    resultString.append(string[index])
}
print(resultString)
```

Comment: [edit] your answer and add some explanation to improve quality of your answer

Comment: Its self explanatory I guess @barbsan

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that!

```
let str = "Hello, world!"
let reversed = String(str.reversed())
print(reversed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Different variation of answer using Character and Index.

```
 //Reverse String
func reverse(str:String)->String{
    var chars = [Character]()
    for i in (0...str.count).reversed() {
       let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
       chars.append(str[index])
    }
    return String(chars)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code-

```
let str = "My name is Kplin Cours"
 var reverseString = ""
 for i in 0..<str.count {
  let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: (str.count - 1) - i)
//  print(String(str[index]))
 reverseString = reverseString + String(str[index])
}

print(reverseString)  //sruoC nilpK si eman yM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let inputstr = "ABCDEFGHIGKLMNPO"
var resultstr = "";
    for strchar in inputstr {
     resultstr = String(strchar) + resultstr
    }
                  print("Result = ",resultstr)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
extension String {
    func invertedEntropy() -> String {
        var word = [Character]()
        for char in self {
            word.insert(char, at: 0)
        }
        return String(word)
    }
}
var palindrome = "TENET"
palindrome.invertedEntropy()

// "TENET"
```