# Reversing a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, swift3

Needed to reverse a swift string, managed to do so with this.

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let reactedText = str.characters.reversed()
let nowBackwards = Array(reactedText)
let answer = String(nowBackwards)
```

And since I find nothing on SO in the subject I post it for some positive votes :) or indeed a better [shorter, as in different] solution.

Comment: See [Reversing the order of a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781943/reversing-the-order-of-a-string-value)

Comment: For Swift 4, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45048639/1187415 to the duplicate (now added three times below :)

Comment: Your right, but forgive me I am in Swift 3.0, updated my question/answer.

Comment: @user3069232: The Swift 3 version is in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41781991/1187415 to the duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the afforementioned code since that is using a loop and is as such an inefficient and somewhat inefficient solution.

Comment: I care about the quality of the code, and I don't think I am alone.

Answer (score 5):

Since in Swift 4, `String`s are `Character` arrays again, you can call `reversed` on the `String` itself and the result will be of type `[Character]`, from which you can initialize a `String`.

```
let stringToBeReversed = "Hello, playground"
let reversedString = String(stringToBeReversed.reversed()) //"dnuorgyalp ,olleH"
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using **Swift 4** :

```
let string = "Hello, playground"
let reversedString = String(string.reversed())
```

Answer (score 0):

reversed method is available in String library

```
let str = "Hello, world!"
let reversed = String(str.reversed())
print(reversed)
```